# Bootstrap Justified Nav Bar not collaspsing correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Building a site using bootstrap.
The main navigation bar is set as justified (nav-justified) -

When it gets to medium, some of the text on the menu is wrapped below and not sure to why this is happening.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: because the texts are too long for the available width on col-md gridspace. you might adjust the font-size of your menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can do something like this to prevent wrapping

```
.nav > li > a {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This will prevent to break words

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing text size at the medium breakpoint:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    #nav-bar {
        font-size: 0.75em;
    }
}
```

Or something of that sort, where `#nav-bar` is the ID of your nav bar (obviously...)

Comment: Thanks JBux - I already tried creating a different break point style but that didnt sort it... However Bhupendra Piprava - did do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
        #navbar a
         {
          font-size: 12px;
         }
  }
```

Try these css lines